# QGIS 2.12/14 Add GPS Point missing geography?

Tags: qgis, gps

I am trying to use the integrated GPS module from QGIS to add data points  to a shapefile while in the field. I managed to get the connection between qgis and the gps working and my location is shown on the map inside QGIS. When I create a new point shapefile, selecting UTM Zone 32N and add a point over the GPS module, a point is added to my shapefile but when I try to zoom to the points I receive the error message "missing geometry". When I try to add a track it works fine.

I have tried using QGIS 2.12 and 2.14 on several different computers with Win 7 and Win 10 and using different projections. While searching for the problem i have not found any solutions.

EDIT:
Problem was fixed in the 2.14 LTR and the Versions since 2.16

Comment: GPS data is alayws in WGS84 EPSG:4326, so I suggest to use that  CRS for any data received from a GPS unit.

Comment: Yep same issue here. i triend on win 7 win 8 mac, it wont work for the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the problem in the field yesterday after changing over to 2.14. I had correct layer type and projections and it would not add a point in the map from the GPS, but it would add the information to the table. I just went back to 2.8.9 all is OK. Seems to be a problem with 2.14.

Comment: I can verify this behavior in 32 Bit Version 2.14.3 on a tablet PC running Windows 8.1.  The GPS unit is a Garmin GLO Bluetooth GPS/Glonass receiver operating at 10HZ.
QGIS will track points, and draw lines in a polyline layer, but it will not plot individual points. Nor does will it update the table with the geometry of the points seemingly recorded.  A row of data is created when a point is recorded, but there are no values stored.

I have tried adding points to both Shape files, and Spatialite files, with no success.

Version 2.8 does not seem to be affected.

Answer (score 1):

I try to keep my desktop projects separate from my field data during data collection, and only go back to my desktop for processing and analysis. I will advice you to get your geometric points on the field and extract them into Qgis as a new layer and move on smoothly.

Comment: Depending of what kind of data you collect in the field, i would do that as well. But as i have to collect data points using GPS and add tons of further information to this specific point, its easier to use Qgis with GPS support in the field. I could use papernotes.. but as soon as it rains.. your notes have a problem, while i can still use qgis on a waterproof device.. furthermore.. i dont have to digitalize the paper stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing a shape file made up of polygons, you cannot add a point to it. If you are logging track points along a line you wish to collect, you need to add the line when you are finished logging the tracking points.
Shape files are restricted to a specific, and single vector type for each layer.
Points
Lines
Polygons
You cannot mix, and match them.

Even though you say you have created a point shape file, it sounds to me as if you have created a polyline, or polygon layer if it is adding a track.

I have also found that it is necessary (for my purposes) to make all of the layers in the project the same projection.  I have ended with the same issue when recording field data in one projection while it is overlaid on a project in another projection. This is especially true if you are going to buffer an object or perform a spatial query on an object that you have logged in the field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created a point shapefile for adding points to my data set. When trying the track function, i used a polyline layer. I will recheck the projection. Maybe thats the fault.